# Video Pause at certain Times

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

I did a project that provides a video (mp4) locally hosted, The project has a video that has 21 pauses. The user watch the video and it pauses reaching the defined points in time. Then the user has to click play to continue. The web site successfully works on all new platforms. Windows, Android browser. Except in iOS safari the video keeps going back to start and not playing. The code only works successfully if the user moved in the timeline for example into 5:00 and waited for it to load then every things goes ok.

My question. How I adjust the code so it would work successfully on Safari on iOS as it is working on chrome in windows and Android Browser 4.0+

Code is :

```
<body>
        <div class="container text-center">
        <video id="vid" controls>
            <source src="vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var video = document.getElementById("vid"); /*The video is found by ID in HTML*/
            var time = [24,34,53,119,155,192,238,258,273,296,323,381,404,432,467,485,520,555,579,610,625]; /*This array holds the times at which the video has to stop. The time is in seconds.*/
        var bools = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]; /*This holds the boolean for when the time has passed.*/
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function()
        {            
            for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) /*The for loop to check for the conditions. 21 stops total*/
            {
                if(this.currentTime >= time[i] && bools[i] == false) {
                this.pause();
                bools[i] = true;
                }
            }
        });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Tried Android browser and Chrome , Internet Explorer 11 on PC works fine.
Tried on Safari on iOS 8.1.3 was not successful ( Video keeps going to 5 sec and back to zero)

link for the project http://stopvid.5gbfree.com/

thanks in advance

Note: I found out that the problem with iPad mini iOS 8.1.3 not loading the video as it should, after moving around in the timeline of the video, the video loads and the JavaScript runs OK. I'm keeping the code for benefit of others. If anyone knows what the exact format that runs on iPad mini without the problem in the loading in beginning I appreciate it. Thanks